# Creating an executable jar including libraries and class and java files through cmd

Tags: java, executable-jar

I’ve tried a few things here and there, I have included all my classes, libraries, MANIFEST.MF, the entire java/bin, along with org.eclipse file that eclipse created, and .classpath, .object file in one folder called testing, and I have attached 2 images of the cmd progress below. The first image, creates an executable jar perfectly but while it is launched, when I press a button to upload a pdf file, it gives the errors in picture two below.

First Image:

http://buiud.com/creating.png "Creates a jar just fine"

Second Image:

http://buiud.com/errorafterPdfLoad.png "NullPointerException error"

Sorry I couldn't add the pictures, due to lack of reputations.

Comment: You don't need the eclipse files for running a java program.

Comment: you need to add the jar containing the class PDDocument in classpath while executing... and regarding adding pictures.. u can directly add stacktrace in the question (just that u need to format it)

Answer (score 0):

Your Class-Path entry in your manifest file is broken, so the JVM cannot find the jar containing the class giving the error.

Comment: My MANIFEST.MF file only contains: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Alma
what should I include to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **maven** I can recommend you to use the [*shade plugin*](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to produce runnable jars with all dependencies (and **manifest** :-)) on-board.

Include this in your **pom.xml**:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <!-- your main class: -->
                  <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

And then execute `mvn clean package shade:shade` to build a jar that you can run from the command line with `java -jar jarfilename.jar`.

Comment: I was suggested to run a maven file, what should I include in that file, and how to name it? Must I still load the MANIFEST.MF file containing; only Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Alma
Inside it?

Answer (score 0):

At first check your MANIFEST file. You no need to add ".MF" but better use .txt format.

Then ensure that you properly set your MANIFEST.txt
look this Warning

---

Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.

---

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

So check the fields:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: NameOfClassWithMain

So make a new line or carriage return after "Main-Class: NameOfClassWithMain"! This field will dissapeared after parsing if you miss that step.
Also carefuly check all files in packages.